# Why does this Javascript function always return true?

Tags: javascript

I built a function *every* that should iterate over an array and return *true* if the *action* (for ex. element < 10) performed on all the elements is *true*. Here's my code:

```
function every(array, action) {
  var trueOrFalse = true
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  
    trueOrFalse = trueOrFalse && action(array[i]);
  if (trueOrFalse = true) return true;
  else  return;
}
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
console.log(every(array1, function(element) {
  return element < 10 
}))
```

I don't see anything wrong.
With *array1*  it returns *true* even if it contains numbers > 10.
Where's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Optimization idea: you don't need to iterate the rest of the elements once you found the first one that does not satisfy your condition. It's called "short circuiting". As a bonus, this will also eliminate your boolean calculation code and the bug which hides there.

Comment: There is a built-in array method for this: [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Is anyone going to mention, why not use the built in [`array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=example) method?

Comment: Don't use the variable at all. The first time that `action` gives a falsey result, `return false` immediately. Then put `return true` after the loop. `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  { if (!action(array[i])) return false } return true`

Comment: Yes, I considered that option. Was just curious to know why mine dind't work.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a linter like ESLint or JSHint to catch common errors like the one you encountered. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: @squint Thanks for the suggestion. I will use them!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (trueOrFalse = true) return true;
```

should be

```
if (trueOrFalse == true) return true;
```

Comment: This. `trueOrFalse = true` is an *assignment*. It *sets* `trueOrFalse` to `true` - and then incidentally returns the value it just set, so the condition is always true.

Comment: `if (trueOrFalse == true)` should be `if (trueOrFalse)`

Comment: Why not just ```return trueOfFalse```?

Comment: @Mark Reed Thanks! For a beginner like me that was the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate trueOrFalse is equal to true
For which you need the double equals

```
if (trueOrFalse == true) return true;
```

Other wise you'll just be making the value of trueOrFalse the same as true

Bonus points:

```
 if (trueOrFalse === true) return true;
```

Using three equal signs is evaluating exactly the same type and value. That isn't required here but is useful to know.

Comment: could use more explanation than just a line of corrected code.

Comment: I assumed it was a typo and didn't require it

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest If you believed it was a typographical error, you should flag the answer as such and move on.

Comment: @mhodges I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is using an incorrect operator, you should be using the `==` operator.

You can use `if (trueOrFalse == true) return true;`

**OR**

you can write it as `if (trueOrFalse) return true;` which will still evaluate it as `if( true )`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `if` statement and rely on good old boolean algebra!

```js
function every(array, action) {
  var trueOrFalse = true
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  
    trueOrFalse = trueOrFalse && action(array[i]);
  return trueOrFalse;
}
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
console.log(every(array1, el => el < 10));
```